# IIS 7.5 - Change of bin files causes restart of other application

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7.5, wcf

I have a problem where change of bin folder of one application, lets call it "X", causes other application ("Y") to restart. It looks like "Y" detects change of X\bin and decides it needs to restart. It causes serious trouble..

Apps are hosted on the same machine (IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008) and have different application pools. Both apps are WCF services.

What is possibly misconfigured?

Comment: Are they nested folders? What does the folder structure look like?

Comment: Applications are in separate folders like: c:\apps\x , c:\apps\y . I though maybe some virtual directories are messed?

Comment: Verifying that the physical paths aren't miss-matched around under the two sites is probably a good thing to check. double-checking the list of applications tied to each apppool is a good thing, too. I've been fooled in there by almost-matching sub-site names before.